# C# Stackdriver Trace credentials from file

Tags: c#, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-trace

I working with Google cloud Stackdriver Trace API with C# (dotnet core) and working according to this [article](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/aspnetcore).

I already added all the needed code and want to try it locally (on my development machine). Since I'm not running from the GCP cloud, I created a new Service Account with the needed permissions. Google said in the article:

> GCP client libraries use Application default credentials (ADC) to find
>   your application's credentials. You provide these credentials by
>   setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable:
>
> ```
> export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path-to-your-service-accounts-private-key
> ```

Now my code fails when reaching this point:

```
services.AddGoogleExceptionLogging(options =>
{
    options.ProjectId = Configuration["Stackdriver:ProjectId"];
    options.ServiceName = Configuration["Stackdriver:ServiceName"];
    options.Version = Configuration["Stackdriver:Version"];
});
```

With the message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Error reading credential file from
>   location C:******.json: Could not find file.
>   Please check the value of the Environment
>   Variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'

For many reasons, I don't want to use the environment variable called `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. Instead, I'm looking for a way to provide it the actual file path, without using an environment variable.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to use the environment variable, have you tried to authenticate using the gcloud SDK ?

As explained [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet#authentication) :

> If running locally for development/testing, you can authenticate using the Google Cloud SDK. Download the SDK if you haven't already, then login by running the following in the command line:
>
> gcloud auth application-default login

Otherwise, the only other way to do it would be specifying the path on your source code.

You should be able to do that with the example provided [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.ErrorReporting.V1Beta1/api/Google.Cloud.ErrorReporting.V1Beta1.ReportErrorsServiceClient.html#Google_Cloud_ErrorReporting_V1Beta1_ReportErrorsServiceClient_Create_Google_Api_Gax_Grpc_ServiceEndpoint_Google_Cloud_ErrorReporting_V1Beta1_ReportErrorsServiceSettings_). Tweak it to suit your specific needs.

> This sample shows how to create a client using credentials loaded from a JSON file:

```
using Google.Cloud.ErrorReporting.V1Beta1;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Grpc.Auth;
using Grpc.Core;
...
GoogleCredential cred = GoogleCredential.FromFile("/path/to/credentials.json");
Channel channel = new Channel(
    ReportErrorsServiceClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host, ReportErrorsServiceClient.DefaultEndpoint.Port, cred.ToChannelCredentials());
ReportErrorsServiceClient client = ReportErrorsServiceClient.Create(channel);
...
// Shutdown the channel when it is no longer required.
channel.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
```

Answer (score -1):

The command you are using

> export
>   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path-to-your-service-accounts-private-key

is used in Linux, but the error your post specified this

> .... Error reading credential file from location C:******.json: Could
>   not find file …..

in this case seems you are using windows and you need to use the command “SET” to assign the value, is located in “[Setting the environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually)” paragraph.

You can also pass the service account key in code, in this case you need to install the [Cloud Storage client library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) you can view an example in the paragraph [“Passing the path to the service account key in code”](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually) where you can see this code for C# and you have a link to GitHub with an example code.

```
// Some APIs, like Storage, accept a credential in their Create()
// method.
public object AuthExplicit(string projectId, string jsonPath)
{
    // Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying
    // the private key file.
    var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonPath);
    var storage = StorageClient.Create(credential);
    // Make an authenticated API request.
    var buckets = storage.ListBuckets(projectId);
    foreach (var bucket in buckets)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(bucket.Name);
    }
    return null;
}
// Other APIs, like Language, accept a channel in their Create()
// method.
public object AuthExplicit(string projectId, string jsonPath)
{
    var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonPath)
        .CreateScoped(LanguageServiceClient.DefaultScopes);
    var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(
        LanguageServiceClient.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(),
        credential.ToChannelCredentials());
    var client = LanguageServiceClient.Create(channel);
    AnalyzeSentiment(client);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code you attached is based on StorageClient, in the example I mentioned - there is no place to use it(`StorageClient`)

Comment: Is an example of use, you can view this line  "var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonPath)" , in the same page where is located this code you can view a button "View On GitHub"  where you can observe a complete code called AuthSample.

Comment: I'm familiar with that code, elsewhere in my project. But here, I don't have a place to use the `credential` variable. When using Storage object, you have overload to use it (`StorageClient.Create(cred)`)